# Youtube v3 api says "exceeded quota" but my usage is 0

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

this a message for Google Support! My API key and request to Youtube API is saying I have exceeded my quota, but I have not used the API and my Quota page shows no usage.

When I make a simple list request (one of perhaps 10 because my app is in development) I receive the following error :

```
array:1 [
"error" => array:3 [
"code" => 403
"message" => "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a 
href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota">quota</a>."
"errors" => array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "message" => "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota">quota</a>."
    "domain" => "youtube.quota"
    "reason" => "quotaExceeded"
  ]
]
```

this is after creating a brand new API key for my application. How can my quota be exceeded when I haven't used it?

Comment: If your message is for Google support, then you've posted it in the wrong place. Google has its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: I'm getting the same response from the YT api. I created a new project, new api key, made some requests and continued development, then an hour later it says I hit my quota. The API and Services page says I've made 2 requests :/

Comment: Did some research and seems the issue is explained here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64695324/upload-via-the-youtube-via-api-set-to-private-locked

Not looking forward to verifying the app as it seems to involve countless steps and require your own secure domain name.

Comment: @FarazH I have verified domain and app but create new YouTube API and enabled API from that project couldn't help, still the same error.