# Upload via the Youtube via api set to Private (locked)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

[image]I have been using the youtube API to upload remotely. But after a while of messing around with the code all the videos that get uploaded gets **"Private (locked)"** due to **Terms and policies**. I cant appeal it either due to "**Appealing this violation is not available**". Just to clarify I have been able to upload before and only recently started getting this error.

Code:
youtube-uploader

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import argparse
import http.client
import httplib2
import os
import random
import time
import videoDetails

import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

from oauth2client import client # Added
from oauth2client import tools # Added
from oauth2client.file import Storage # Added


# Explicitly tell the underlying HTTP transport library not to retry, since
# we are handling retry logic ourselves.
httplib2.RETRIES = 1

# Maximum number of times to retry before giving up.
MAX_RETRIES = 10

# Always retry when these exceptions are raised.
RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS = (httplib2.HttpLib2Error, IOError, http.client.NotConnected,
  http.client.IncompleteRead, http.client.ImproperConnectionState,
  http.client.CannotSendRequest, http.client.CannotSendHeader,
  http.client.ResponseNotReady, http.client.BadStatusLine)

# Always retry when an apiclient.errors.HttpError with one of these status
# codes is raised.
RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504]

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = 'client_secrets.json'

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload']
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
API_VERSION = 'v3'

VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES = ('public', 'private', 'unlisted')



def get_authenticated_service(): # Modified
    credential_path = os.path.join('./', 'credentials.json')
    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)

def initialize_upload(youtube, options):
  tags = None
  if options.keywords:
    tags = options.keywords.split(',')

  body=dict(
    snippet=dict(
      title=options.getFileName("video").split(".", 1)[0],
      description=options.description,
      tags=tags,
      categoryId=options.category
    ),
    status=dict(
      privacyStatus=options.privacyStatus
    )
  )

  # Call the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
  videoPath = "/Users\caspe\OneDrive\Documents\Övrigt\Kodning\AwsCSGO\Video\%s" % (options.getFileName("video"))
  insert_request = youtube.videos().insert(
    part=','.join(body.keys()),
    body=body,
    media_body=MediaFileUpload(videoPath, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
  )

  resumable_upload(insert_request, options)

# This method implements an exponential backoff strategy to resume a
# failed upload.
def resumable_upload(request, options):
  response = None
  error = None
  retry = 0
  while response is None:
    try:
      print('Uploading file...')
      status, response = request.next_chunk()
      if response is not None:
        if 'id' in response:
          print ('The video with the id %s was successfully uploaded!' % response['id'])
          
          # upload thumbnail for Video
          options.insertThumbnail(youtube, response['id'])
        else:
          exit('The upload failed with an unexpected response: %s' % response)
    except HttpError as e:
      if e.resp.status in RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES:
        error = 'A retriable HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s' % (e.resp.status,
                                                             e.content)
      else:
        raise
    except RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS as e:
      error = 'A retriable error occurred: %s' % e

    if error is not None:
      print (error)
      retry += 1
      if retry > MAX_RETRIES:
        exit('No longer attempting to retry.')

      max_sleep = 2 ** retry
      sleep_seconds = random.random() * max_sleep
      print ('Sleeping %f seconds and then retrying...') % sleep_seconds
      time.sleep(sleep_seconds)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  args = videoDetails.Video()
  youtube = get_authenticated_service()

  try:
    initialize_upload(youtube, args)
  except HttpError as e:
    print ('An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s') % (e.resp.status, e.content)
```

videoDetails

```
import os
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

class Video:
    description = "test description"
    category = "22"
    keywords = "test"
    privacyStatus = "public"

    def getFileName(self, type):
        for file in os.listdir("/Users\caspe\OneDrive\Documents\Övrigt\Kodning\AwsCSGO\Video"):
            if type == "video" and file.split(".", 1)[1] != "jpg":
                return file
                break
            elif type == "thumbnail" and file.split(".", 1)[1] != "mp4":
                return file
                break

    def insertThumbnail(self, youtube, videoId):
        thumnailPath = "/Users\caspe\OneDrive\Documents\Övrigt\Kodning\AwsCSGO\Video\%s" % (self.getFileName("thumbnail"))

        request = youtube.thumbnails().set(
            videoId=videoId,
            media_body=MediaFileUpload(thumnailPath)
        )
        response = request.execute()
        print(response)
```

Comment: So, you are able to upload but it's just that it becomes private?

Comment: yes, added an image to clearify

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you check the documentation for [Video.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) you will find the following at the top of the page.  This is a new policy that is recently beginning to be enforced.

[image]

Until your application has been verified all videos you upload will be set to private.  You need to go though the audit first then you will be able to upload public videos.

Note once your application has been verified this will not automatically set all existing previously uploaded videos to public you will need to do that yourself.

Comment: Alright, thank you, a bit weird because I have been able to upload 20+ videos and only recently received the error.

Comment: It appears that the enforcement of this new policy did not roll out right away world wide it seams to be some kind of slow roll out.

Comment: ffs ok.... Thanks very much for the answer :) Lets do audits

Comment: I also had this problem today and it scks. I had to use api today because browser upload never progressed